# Rails nested form attributes are not being permits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a model named team group and a nested model salesforce_user_roles my form is sending me below information

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"create_salesforce_user"=>"0", "delete_salesforce_user"=>"1", 
"salesforce_user_roles_attributes"=>
<ActionController::Parameters {
"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"11", "name"=>"Director, Channel Sales", "role_id"=>"00E7F000001AY", "_destroy"=>"false"}>, 
"1577184453507"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Eastern Sales Team", "role_id"=>"00E7F0000016xFLUAY", "_destroy"=>"false"} } >} >
```

For security, I am permitting only a few params. I am using `params.require(:team_group).permit(:name, :salesforce_user_roles_attributes)`
 to permit the nested model attribute but it's not saving anything in my database. How can I permit nested model params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm, have you added `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in model?

If yes, then follow this practice to permit them:

`params.require(:team_group).permit(:name, salesforce_user_roles_attributes: [:id, :name, :role_id, :_destroy])`

Thank you